# Excluding records based on multiple variables

Tags: sql, ms-access

SQL noob here.  I'm using MS Access to query a table of streetlight data to exclude lights of a certain size and only where the fixture type is a variant of "Cobra".  Is anyone kind enough to give me some guidance on what I might be doing wrong?

I can produce the lights I need to be excluded with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Lighting 
WHERE Lighting.TYPE_FIXTURE LIKE '*cobra*' 
AND Lighting.SIZ < '16'
```

Simple enough.  I thought this would be easy to tweak a little bit to get it to exclude these instead of produce them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Lighting
WHERE Lighting.TYPE_FIXTURE NOT IN ('*Cobra*') 
AND Lighting.SIZ NOT IN ('10', '15')
```

This code excludes the lights I need to be excluded, but also every other type of light that is 100 or 150w.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to exclude ONLY Cobra lights 150w or less.

Through extensive internet research, I tried using an IIF expression to produce a temporary column that would have a value of 0 or 1, depending on if it needed to be excluded or not,

```
SELECT *
    ,IIf(Lighting.TYPE_FIXTURE LIKE "*cobra*" AND Lighting.SIZ < 15, 0, 1) AS IncludeFlag
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM Lighting

SELECT *
FROM #MyTempTable
WHERE IncludeFlag = 1
```

but my only result is an error message that I don't know how to resolve.  I've spent all day on this one query and I'm starting to pull my hair out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting from a TRUE and TRUE to a NOT(TRUE and TRUE) involves distributing the NOT inside the brackets and switch the AND to an OR.

The following should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Lighting
WHERE Lighting.TYPE_FIXTURE Not Like '*cobra*' OR Lighting.SIZ>='16';
```

Comment: Other notes: the keyword IN is used to test if your test value is part of a set, so if you wanted to test if 10 is in the set (1,2,10,200).  I don't think you can use the wildcard "*" with IN--each item has to be explicit.  Also, your sizes are text (strings) so "2" will be greater than "10" as Access will be doing an alphabetic test.  If you're sizes are not text, then you don't need quotes around 10, 15, or 16.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I knew I was just doing something stupid and this had to be much simpler than I was making it.  I appreciate the info.

Comment: I was using AND on purpose thinking I needed it to take both variables into account.  I see now that the NOT affects both instead.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Lighting 
WHERE (Lighting.TYPE_FIXTURE NOT LIKE '*cobra*' 
AND Lighting.SIZ < '16')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that query produces a list of only the lights 150w or less that are not Cobra variants.  I need instead to exclude only Cobra variant lights that are 150w or less.  Hope that makes sense.